# How to handle shell expansions in GNU Make under Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, makefile, gnu-make, brace-expansion

Given this very simple `Makefile`:

```
all:
    @mkdir -pv test/{a,b}
```

I get this output on OS X 10.6.8 and CentOS 5.5:

```
mkdir: created directory `test'
mkdir: created directory `test/a'
mkdir: created directory `test/b'
```

But on Ubuntu 11.04 I get this:

```
mkdir: created directory `test'
mkdir: created directory `test/{a,b}'
```

Running the command `mkdir -pv test/{a,b}` manually in the shell on all platforms gives the expected result.

The version of GNU Make is the same on all platforms:

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program is built for [PLATFORM]
```

What's different under Ubuntu and why doesn't the shell expansion work there?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The problem is probably that Make spawns `/bin/sh`. It is usually a symlink to your system's default shell.

### Option 1

You could make sure it points to bash (as this is a bashism). Probably, it is now /bin/dash or /bin/sh, depending on your version of Ubuntu.

### Option 2

Easier option:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

all:
    @echo a{3,4}
    @bash -c 'echo a{3,4}'
```

This prints the same output twice unless you comment-out the `SHELL=` line

### Option 3

If you can't/don't want to modify the make file, you can invoke it like so:

```
make SHELL=/bin/bash
```

beware of interactions with sub-makefiles or includes. You might want to look at the `make -e` option and the make `export` keyword: http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Variables_002fRecursion.html

Comment: This was the case. We're having makefiles that should run on all these different platforms, so setting the `SHELL` variable was the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Make has [a function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#index-file-name-prefix_002c-adding) to do this:

```
    @mkdir -pv $(addprefix test/,a b)
```

gets expanded to

```
    @mkdir -pv test/a test/b
```

[The docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) are very thorough.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long, long time since I've used Make...

There are several ways to specify a particular shell to use. The default shell for old Make was the original Bourne shell. If you wanted a different shell, you had to set it yourself.

You're using Linux and GNU, so I'll assume that you're using BASH as the default shell. Try this command in your Make:

```
echo "random = $RANDOM"
```

If this simply prints `random =` and doesn't include a random number, your Make is using Bourne shell as its default shell instead of BASH. (Which is weird because I didn't think there was a real Bourne shell in Linux...) To get around this:

- You can add in a `SHELL` macro pointing to the BASH shell.
- You can include the shell in your command.

Instead of:

```
@mkdir -pv test/{a,b}
```

Put this:

```
/bin/bash -c @mkdir -pv test/{a,b}
```

This specifies you want to use BASH and not the standard /bin/sh Bourne shell.

If the `echo random = $RANDOM` does print a random number, you're using BASH (or at least Kornshell), but the BRACE EXPANSION might not be set. Try using this in your Makefile:

```
set -o
```

And make sure `braceexpand` is on. It could be off when you run Make.