# Use $RANDOM in a makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, terminal

I am making a makefile to rename files with a random number in it (I am a newbie in shell script). I don't understand why, but when I run the file $rand is given the value 'ANDOM'. When I run this outside of the makefile it works.

I run this in the Mac os terminal, in case it's helpful.

```
all: renamefiles

renamefiles:
    rand=$RANDOM && mv myfile.css $rand-myfile.css && mv myotherfile.css $rand-myotherfile.css
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Wouldn't it be easier/better to use a date/time stamp so that the renamed files are listed in date order?
2. You need to use two `$` signs in the `makefile` for each `$` that you want the shell to see.

Thus:

```
all: renamefiles

renamefiles:
    rand=$$RANDOM && \
    mv myfile.css      $$rand-myfile.css && \
    mv myotherfile.css $$rand-myotherfile.css
```

Or, with date/time stamps:

```
all: renamefiles

renamefiles:
    time=$$(date +'%Y%m%d-%H%M%S') && \
    mv myfile.css      $$time-myfile.css && \
    mv myotherfile.css $$time-myotherfile.css
```

Comment: $RANDOM was the first I thought about but the time is definitely better. Thank you

Comment: Be aware that `$RANDOM` is a builtin bash variable and not in all shells (unlike `$$`, should be available in all POSIX-compliant shells, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8281456/470117).
Make use the default shell. To specify which shell make will use, define a variable: `SHELL = /bin/bash` or (via cmd line argument) `make SHELL=/bin/bash`
See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6681727/470117

Answer (score 2):

To use a random number within one or multiple make variables, the following works fine for me:

```
FOO="some string with \"$$rand\" in it"
BAR=" you may use it $$rand times."
foobar:
    rand=$$$$ && \
    echo $(FOO) $(BAR)
```

Comment: Thanks very much to @mems ' comment regarding the accepted answer. Although this answer does not tackle the stated use case, it fits the question I hope :)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to surround a multi-letter macro name with braces (or parentheses), for example

```
${RANDOM}
$(RANDOM)
```

[**ref**](http://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Makefile)

Comment: This evaluates the `make` variable RANDOM (which probably won't exist and isn't random).  In this case, I think the trick is that you write `$$` to get one `$` to the shell:  `rand=$$RANDOM` or `rand=$${RANDOM}`.