# Where to find AWS S3 Deployment Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I'm following along with [Serverless Watermark using AWS Lambda Layers & FFmpeg - DevOpStar](https://devopstar.com/2019/01/28/serverless-watermark-using-aws-lambda-layers-ffmpeg/) and I get stuck right at 
Deployment Key.

Where do I get my Deployment Key?

I've already created a bucket on AWS can't find a Key associated with it.

I am stuck here:

[image: Deployment key]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that particular tutorial, the `DEPLOYMENT_KEY` is simply referring to the name of the object to be stored in Amazon S3.

For objects in Amazon S3, the filename is referred to as the `Key` and it includes the full path, such as:

```
resources/aws-ffmpeg-serverless-convert/ffmpeg-1234.zip
```

I suspect that those lines in the `MAKE` file can be used as-supplied, without having to make any changes.

The `$$RANDOM` command will generate a random name to avoid clashes. See: [Use $RANDOM in a makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14409906/174777)

**Bottom line:** You only need to change the `DEPLOYMENT_BUCKET_NAME` to a bucket that you created.